# C# Uri.EscapeDataString adds incorrect "%25" in the decoded string

Tags: c#, urlencode

I'm trying to UrlEncode a web address using Uri.EscapeDataString, but the result isn't correct. Here's an example:

```
string url = "https://mega.co.nz/#!GVZFwAbB!NzdN2jp7A_WmQBLC4RJrCX8SzixFIEo7oZZARaMAmXQ";
string encodedUrl = Uri.EscapeDataString(url);
```

Expected result would be:

```
https%3a%2f%2fmega.co.nz%2f%23!GVZFwAbB!NzdN2jp7A_WmQBLC4RJrCX8SzixFIEo7oZZARaMAmXQ
```

But the actual one is:

```
https%253a%252f%252fmega.co.nz%252f%2523%21GVZFwAbB%21NzdN2jp7A_WmQBLC4RJrCX8SzixFIEo7oZZARaMAmXQ
```

As you can see, there's a bunch of extra `%25`s that don't belong there. Isn't `%25` the encode for "`%`"? There are no `%`s in my original string... what's going on?

EDIT: I can't use the `System.Web assembly` for this project, so unfortunately I can't use the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` method for this.

Comment: It is strange but your code works properly https://dotnetfiddle.net/ARkx9c

Comment: I don't see this happening. `Uri.EscapeDataString` returns `https%3A%2F%2Fmega.co.nz%2F%23!GVZFwAbB!NzdN2jp7A_WmQBLC4RJrCX8SzixFIEo7oZZARaMAmXQ` for me. Apparently the value returned is later encoded again in your project.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan and GSerg:  Well, there's already an inconsistency right there: Hamlet's JSFiddle encodes "!" to "%21" while your string still has "!". And on my machine it adds the %25 and ALSO converts "!" to "%21". It seems to behave differently on each machine... I'm lost to be honest. GSerg output is the only correct one, but I don't know how to obtain it...

Comment: It depends on .NET version. v4.5 encodes `!` but v4.0 doesn't.

Comment: .NET v4.5 encodes `!` as `%21`, .NET v4 and below leave it as `!`. Neither of the versions double-encodes the `%25`. I believe the `!` is not an issue after all, and you should find the place in your project where the second encoding happens (might be done implicitly by a framework you are using).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after searching around a bit more, it seems that this does the job, without relying on system web:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

The encoding is the correct one, without `%25`s.

Answer (score 2):

`Uri.EscapeDataString` doesn't encode URL. Use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
string url = "https://mega.co.nz/#!GVZFwAbB!NzdN2jp7A_WmQBLC4RJrCX8SzixFIEo7oZZARaMAmXQ";
string encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Result is:

```
https%3a%2f%2fmega.co.nz%2f%23!GVZFwAbB!NzdN2jp7A_WmQBLC4RJrCX8SzixFIEo7oZZARaMAmXQ
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for reasons I won't bore you with, I can't use the System.Web assembly for this project, so I can't use HttpUtility